# How many solutions does this equation have xyz + yvv = xxzy?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following equation:

```
xyz + yvv = xxzy
```

where all numerical digit replaced by letters (x, y, z and v). How many solutions does this equation have, if all numbers matches different letters? 
I have found only one solution:

```
194 + 955 = 1149
```

But, I think, that there is some trick in this task. And there is more than one solution

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** note if $xyz + yvv = xxzy$ for digits, then: $$100x + 10y + z +100y + 11v = 1100x + 10z + y$$ This reduces to $$11v = 1000x + 9z - 109y$$ Now, reducing this modulo 11 gives: $$ 0 = y-x-2z \pmod{11}$$ Can you continue from this - note that since we are summing two $3$ digit numbers (I assume $x$ isn't $0$) our number $xxzy$ will definitely be less than $2000$, this means $x$ must be.....? From this value of $x$, what value must $y$ take since if $y<8$ what do you know about the left hand side of your equation....?

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can just brute force it with for example mathematica which would look like

`Count[
      Flatten[
            Table[
                  TrueQ[
    x*100 + y*10 + z + y*100 + v*10 + v*1 == x*1100 + z*10 + y],
    {x,0, 9}, {y, 0, 9}, {z, 0, 9}, {v, 0, 9}]], 
      True]`

which gives 2 as an answer. But with some thinking you don't need to check every case, because we have something like $a+b=c$ where we know that $a$ and $b$ are strictly smaller than $1000$, so the only possible cases for $x$ are $0$ or $1$.

If $x=0$ for the very same reason it follows that $y=0$ so we got the equation 
$z+v\cdot 11= z\cdot 10$. If we now check how often both sides to have $2$ as a factor we see, that $z$ must be odd and $v$ must be even. 
Furthermore we check this equation modulo $5$ which yields 
$z+v=0 \mod 5$.

Now there aren't that many cases left in special we only need to check the cases $z=1$ and $z=3$ because in the other cases $v$ will be to small for the equation to hold.

In the case that $x=1$ you get immediately that $y=9$ for the same reason as above. So the equation is 
$190+ z +900+ v\times 11 = 1109 +z\times 10$  which is equivalent to 
$$z + v\times 11 = 19 + z \times 10$$

Looking on the equation modulo $2$ yiels 
$z+v=1\mod 2$ meaning one of $z,v$ is odd and the other is even. Similar arguments show that your solution is the only nontrivial.